# Links in jQuery Validation error messages don't work on first click

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

If I customise a jQuery Validation (i.e. https://jqueryvalidation.org/) error message to include a link, e.g.

```
$("form").validate({
  messages: {
    foo: {
      required: 'This field is required, <a href="#" onclick="alert(0); return false;">click here to find out why</a>',
    }
  }
});
```

The link doesn't work on the first click, only on second and subsequent.

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jo6myLf9/

What's going on?

Comment: It appears to be a `focus` issue. In your fiddle, click the `submit` button. You'll see the input box is still in focus (flashing cursor). Click *next* to the input box (just on the blank space), then click the link. It will work 1st time. But if you put the input box back in focus and try the link again, it will not fire. Not a solution, but it's a direction for ya.

Answer (score 0):

Per my comment above, it appears to be a *focus* issue.

You can include the `focusInvalid` option, and set it to `false` which, per the docs, "*disables focusing of invalid elements*" which is causing your problem.

```
focusInvalid: false
```

Full code:

```
$("form").validate({
  focusInvalid: false,
  messages: {
    foo: {
      required: 'This field is required, <a href="#" onclick="alert(0); return false;">click here to find out why</a>',
    }
  }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xrufp5mx/1/)

However, if element focus is important to you and your application (UX?), this won't help you.

Comment: Thanks Marcus. Unfortunately this doesn't work when the error message is dynamically displayed during typing, e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/xrufp5mx/2/. I don't understand what it is about the error link which makes it different from a normal link, which works first click regardless of focus.

Comment: Removing `generated="true"` from the `<label>` (which is wrapping the link in question) resolves the issue entirely. I've never used this library myself, but you might want to look into why that attribute is being added to the `label` and what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the expected result of alert on single click and focus after that alert use below option

```
      $("form").validate({
        focusInvalid: false,
        messages: {
          foo: {
            required: 'This field is required, <a href="#" onclick="alert(0);$(\'#foo\').focus(); return false;">click here to find out why</a>',
          }
        }
      });
```

In onclick function , i set focus back to that input field  and focusInvalid: false will display alert on single click ,which will cover all scenarios

JSFiddle -http://jsfiddle.net/Nagasai_Aytha/6oer7bkg/2/ for reference

Hope this works for you.

Comment: You would never need to use an inline click handler when you have jQuery at your disposal.   http://jsfiddle.net/Lhmhyjtu/